# Unable to use the command mouse_down_at in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, html5-canvas, robotframework

I'm busy with the UI-automation of an application where a drawing in a style comparable to the Paint-application can be made. In the application under test this area is made via a canvas-element.

My goal is to make a kind of drawing on this canvas via Selenium and the Robot Framework, e.g. like drawing a line:

1. mouse press on certain position
2. mouse move to the new position
3. release mouse on the new position

In the [official documentation](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html) of the Selenium2Library for the Robot Framework I saw that there is no keyword which fits my needs (the keyword 'Click Element At Coordinates' didn't work). However, via a [search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/x-qpQ89_RP0) I found out that there is a keyword 'mouse_down_at', but this keyword is not accessible in the standard Robot Framework. However, the keyword 'mouse_down_at' is present in the file selenium.py which is in Selenium-folder (Python site-packages).

Now, I'm looking for a way to access this keyword 'mouse_down_at' in the Robot Framework.
I already tried by myself to write a wrapper library around this, but was unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own version of Selenium2Library and use that instead of the standard Selenium2Lib. Something like this:

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class Selenium2Improved(Selenium2Library):
    '''Sometimes Selenium2Library just dont go far enough.'''

    def __init__(self, timeout=5.0, implicit_wait=0.0, run_on_failure='Capture Page Screenshot'):
        super(Selenium2Improved, self).__init__()

    def mouse_down_at(self, locator, coordx, coordy):
        element = self._element_find(locator, True, False)
        if element is None:
            raise AssertionError("ERROR: Element %s not found." % (locator))
        ActionChains(self._current_browser()).move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(coordx, coordy).click_and_hold().perform()

    def mouse_up_at(self, locator, coordx, coordy):
        element = self._element_find(locator, True, False)
        if element is None:
            raise AssertionError("ERROR: Element %s not found." % (locator))
        ActionChains(self._current_browser()).move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(coordx, coordy).release().perform()
```

Comment: Hi Harri, thanks a lot for your reply. Because of your code I could get my text to work.

Small glitch is that you don't actually see the mouse cursor moving, but the test passes. A colleague told me that he has seen such behavior before.

Comment: Your colleagues memory is correct. With SeleniumLibrary (the one that used Selenium Remote Controller API) you could do something like `Call Selenium API    mouseDownAt    element    coordx,coordy` and then the same for `mouseUpAt` and browser would execute Javascript that would move the cursor and you could actully see the cursor moving (although it was really buggy). Selenium2Library (uses WebDriver API) works differently and does not have the Call Selenium API keyword.